# UserManager steps out of the function without throwing any Excepcion

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make my MVC app create initial preview users in the database with following code:

```
private async Task CreateStartupUsers(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            List<IdentityUser> admins = new List<IdentityUser>
            {
                new IdentityUser
                {
                    UserName = "admin@admin.com",
                    Email = "admin@admin.com",
                    EmailConfirmed = true
                }
            };

...

foreach (var admin in admins)
            {
                if (await userManager.FindByNameAsync(admin.UserName) != null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                await userManager.CreateAsync(admin, DefaultPassword);
                IdentityUser user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(admin.UserName);
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
            }
```

I honestly don't see any issues here besides calling this funcion in non async `public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }`, but i don't think it explains the fact, that during debugging the instruction calling `userManager` is not executing and steps out of the function.

I also have made a very similar function for creating initial user roles and it work perfectly.

```
private async Task CreateRoles(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            var roles = new List<IdentityRole>
            {
                new IdentityRole
                {
                    Name = "Admin"
                },
                new IdentityRole
                {
                    Name = "Employee"
                },
                new IdentityRole
                {
                    Name = "Customer"
                }
            };

            foreach (var role in roles)
            {
                if (await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role.Name)) continue;
                var result = await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
                if (result.Succeeded) continue;

                throw new Exception($"Could not create '{role.Name}' role.");
            }
        }
```

Those functions are called in StartUp.cs in `Configure` function as seen below:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
                CreateRoles(roleManager);
                CreateStartupUsers(userManager);
            }
```

Comment: Can you post your ```ConfigureService``` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `Configuration` method was called synchronous and thier submethods asynchronically the method for creating user was not finish before `Configuration` has finished. Since `Configuration` has to return `void` for the builder i had to make following changes:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
                CreateRolesAndUsersAsync(roleManager, userManager).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
```

Adding `GetAwaiter()` and `GetResult()` to the method containing both asynchronous methods I wanted to execute I've secured the execution of them and got expected results.